# Spring Boot JPA Hibernate rest service returns an empty response

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a spring boot application with JPA hibernate and a oracle DB. However, my get request keeps coming up as an empty array (ie: []). I'm not sure what I did wrong? I've tried it with other queries too (a custom one or findOne() and it just returns empty). It runs perfectly fine and doesn't provide any error messages.

Also: Hibernate shows the sql queries ran in console. When I run it myself on the oracle DB, it produces data.

This is my Employee Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee", schema = "store")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

@EmbeddedId
private EmployeeID id;

@Column(name="SALES_MADET0")
private Number salesMadeT0;

@Column(name="AVG_SALEST0")
private Float avgSalesT0;

@Column(name="FAVORITE_ITEM")
private String favoriteItem;

//Getters and Setters here
}
```

This is my EmployeeId Embedded Entity

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeID implements Serializable {

@Column(name ="EMPLOYEE_NAME")
private String employeeName;

@Column(name="DATE_STARTED")
private Date dateStarted;

//getters and setters here
}
```

This is my repository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, 
EmployeeID> {}
```

This is my service

```
@Component
public class EmployeeService {

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeerepository;

public Iterable<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeerepository.findAll();
}
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired
public EmployeeService employeeservice;

@RequestMapping(value="/getAllEmployees", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Employee> getAllEmployee(HttpServletRequest request){
    return employeeservice.getAllEmployees();
}
```

Comment: try printing list in controller method before send response ?

Comment: Hi! I have and it's empty..

Comment: the call of your service is wrong, should be employeeservice.getAllEmployees();

Comment: Hi! Oops, I must've accidentally deleted that when I was writing the question. It's been edited but that was not my issue!

Comment: Can you confirm that Hibernate is pointed at your real database and not an empty in-memory H2 instance?

Comment: try to use public @ResponseBody Iterable<Employee> getAllEmployee...

Comment: @Gnk I tried that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry, I'm new to hibernate. How do I confirm that?

Comment: check schema and db names, and make sure hibernate actually retrieved data or not by looking at logs

Comment: Can you change extended class of Repository to JpaRepository  instead of CrudRepository?

Comment: @drowny That's not the problem; if Spring Data were confused, it'd throw an exception on startup.

Comment: Hey all! I ended up fixing the problem. It turned out to be a database issue. However, I'm now getting an error "org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: Could not deserialize" issue. I'm not sure what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: please add error details in question..